# PHP MySQL Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object, just don't get it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a slight problem with my php page which I just don't understand.

I have a connect.php file which I include at the top of my php page using *require("connect.php")*.

Using the following code I'm able to populate a drop menu in my form without any issues.

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable"); 
$stmt->execute();
$rowsec = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

When I submit the page all field details are captured and an entry is made in the database but I get the following error message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in..line 71

line 71 is  **$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);**

Now I found that if I add the following line it works without any errors:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydatabase", "user", "pass"); //This line here
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable"); 
$stmt->execute();
$rowsec = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

In my require("connect.php") I have:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=clincoding", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

To get the data out of the table for the drop menu I use:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable"); 
$stmt->execute();
$rowsec = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

for the drop menu I use:

```
<label for="dropmen">Select a section</label><br />
                <select name="dropmen" id="dropmen">
                    <?php foreach ($rowsec as $value) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php  echo $value[1] ?>"><?php  echo $value[2] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
```

Could someone tell me why the **require("connect.php")** which has the same connection does not work? Trying to get my head around PDO process this has got me stumped.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I would guess, that the `$conn` element is not visible. Are you trying the run this code inside of a function? Or have you included the "connect.php" inside of a function?

Comment: Show us the relevant code in connect.php that establishes the connection.  Perhaps you just need to make $conn global after it is initialized.  Then any other function can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check 7th line of connect.php

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=clincoding", $username, $password);
```

and change it as

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=clincoding", $username, $password);
```

read about this function from php.net and use it as

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```